# How to embed a Picture from an external Website (with url parameters) that displays a Canvas or Image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am pretty new to Frontend Development, so sorry, if this is an easy Problem and I am overlooking something easy, but I am now struggling for 2 days with that problem.

I am currently trying to embed a picture of an external Source into an html page I build. I don't really care if I have to do this with CSS as background image, or as  via html.

I am in full control of the source, namely, its a Github-Pages Site I build, and it displays a map snipped (of a Game) at specific coordinates which I specify via parameters in the URL.

I build the picture with a Canvas, and did recently try to convert said Canvas to an png and only display that in the websites body. With no luck, whatever I try, I can't get it to display something with the link I need.

What I basicly need is: I have an URL that looks like this: githubpagessite.com?x=500&y=-500 and want to embed this link in my code, so that the parameters can be changed, and it will display a different position of said map. I know that usually I would have to have a link that redirects directly to that source githubpagessite.com/....png but this is not possible, since I need the parameters in the url.

I would like to solve this purely by JS/HTML/CSS or JQuery, if possible. I have looked into AJAX since I heard this could solve my problem, but I didn't get it to work at all.

Edit: Let me specify a bit further, what my problem is.

I run a github pages site, which is basicly just consisting of this script:
(I removed unnecessary parts, it should be clear, that I am building an Image with canvas, that I display on this website)

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const x = urlParams.get('x') //X coordinate retrieved from link
const y = urlParams.get('y') //Y coordinate retrieved from link

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//images gets loaded etc. 



ctx.drawImage(images[0], coordinateXPosition, coordinateYPosition, snippedWidth, snippedHeight, 0, 0, snippedWidth, snippedHeight); 
//Image of the map gets drawn at the specific coordinate with a specific height.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

What I then want to do is, to somehow, over the querylink with that above mentioned style, embed 2 pictures, with different coordinates, on another site.

The Problem is, that the requestlink itself does not lead to any png or jpg ressource, since this ressource is only created when the request link is sent, and is only visible for as long as the browser window is open, there is no picture getting saved because of that request link or sth.

I want to be able to somehow retrieve the picture from the website, that was created.
After Realising the above might be the wrong solutionand therefore used toDataURL() to turn the Canvas into one Picture.

(Which then only has the image as  element in the body looking st like this:

```
img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh....>
```

I hope this makes the problem clearer.

Comment: It is expected for askers to post what they have tried and their code attempts in doing this. create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: @I_love_vegetables I tried to explain my problem further and provided some code. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Fantastic, Goodluck and happy coding :D

Answer (score 0):

What I basically understood is that you have an image on an external website and want to embed it on this page you are working on. So, if that is the problem use the below code-

```html
<img src="https://www.githubpagessite.com?x=500&y=-500">
```

Comment: Hi, sadly, this doesn't help me. I know how to embed a picture itself, but I don't know how to do it in this specific case. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: No issues. I am not taking it hard. I gave this answer as you are new to front end dev so i thought u must not know this.. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Dw, leave it up, so others know I already tried that one :)

Comment: Sure Ok I wont :o)